# Aplicativo crashando sem motivo - Ionic 4

Tags: node.js, ionic, typescript

Estou fazendo um aplicativo (Ionic4, typescript, node.js) para gravação e reprodução de áudio onde o usuário grava o som e após o áudio é apresentado com um botão de play;
Logo após o usuário dar permissão para armazenar dados e acesso do microfone, o aplicativo fecha sem nenhum erro no debugger.

Segue o código do .html e do .ts

audios.page.html

```
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-button expand="full" (click)="capturarAudio()">Gravar áudio</ion-button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-list>

    <ion-item *ngFor="let arquivo of mediaFiles" tappable (click)="play(arquivo)" text-wrap>
    {{ file.name }}
    <p>{{file.size / 1000 / 1000 | number }} MB </p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

audios.page.ts

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { MediaCapture } from '@ionic-native/media-capture/ngx';
    import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage';
    import { Media, MediaObject  } from '@ionic-native/media/ngx';
    import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
    import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

    const MEDIA_FILES_KEY = 'mediafiles';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-audios',
      templateUrl: './audios.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./audios.page.scss'],
    })
    export class AudiosPage implements OnInit {

      mediaFiles = [];
      constructor(private mediaCapture: MediaCapture, private storage: Storage, private media: Media, private file: File) { 


      }

      ionViewDidLoad(){

        this.storage.get(MEDIA_FILES_KEY).then(res => {
          this.mediaFiles = JSON.parse(res) || [];
        });
      }

      capturarAudio(){
        this.mediaCapture.captureAudio().then( res => {
          this.storeMediaFiles(res);
        })
      }

      play(myFile){
        console.log('play', myFile);
        if (myFile.name.indexOf('.wav') > -1){
          const audioFile: MediaObject = this.media.create(myFile.localURL)
          audioFile.play();
        }
      }

      storeMediaFiles(files){
        console.log('storage:', files);
        this.storage.get(MEDIA_FILES_KEY).then(res => {
          if (res) {
            let arr = JSON.parse(res);
            arr = arr.concat(files);
            this.storage.set(MEDIA_FILES_KEY, JSON.stringify(arr))
          } else {
            this.storage.set(MEDIA_FILES_KEY, JSON.stringify(files))
          }
          this.mediaFiles = this.mediaFiles.concat(files);
        })

      }

        ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

EDIT1: Dando uma olhada no Logcat obtenho esse erro:

```
E/PluginManager: Uncaught exception from plugin
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.provider.MediaStore.RECORD_SOUND }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1899)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1589)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4229)
        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.startActivityForResult(CordovaActivity.java:343)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4187)
        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterfaceImpl.startActivityForResult(CordovaInterfaceImpl.java:68)
        at org.apache.cordova.mediacapture.Capture.captureAudio(Capture.java:234)
        at org.apache.cordova.mediacapture.Capture.execute(Capture.java:132)
        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:98)
        at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:59)
        at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemExposedJsApi.exec(SystemExposedJsApi.java:41)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Comment: Isso pode ter haver com o plugin que instalou. Instalou algum?

Comment: Somente o necessário, media-capture.

Comment: Você está testando em algum celular ou no Browser ?

Comment: Estou rodando no celular, testei em dois e ambos acontece a mesma coisa

Answer (score 0):

A exception gerada explica o erro:

- `E/PluginManager: Uncaught exception from plugin`: significa que o gerenciador de plugins detectou uma falha não tratada pelo plugin (o que pode indicar um problema no mesmo);
- `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException`: essa exceção ocorre quando uma activity não é encontrada para resolver uma `Intent`. Na prática isso ocorre quando você tenta iniciar um aplicativo ou serviço que não existe no sistema - ele pode simplesmente não estar instalado;
- `No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.provider.MediaStore.RECORD_SOUND }`: este é o detalhe da `ActivityNotFoundException`, que indica que não foi encontrada uma activity para satisfazer a intent.

O erro acontece por que o sistema não foi capaz de abrir o app gravador de som. Acredito que será necessário implementar a funcionalidade por meio de outro plugin - [este](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-audio-recorder) deve servir.

Caso você não queira implementar essa funcionalidade, pode apenas checar se existe algum app de gravação instalado. No Android, em código java, isso pode ser feito desta maneira:

```java
PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "Não foi possível iniciar a Intent");
}
```